# "Sign in with Apple" redirects to a blank white page on PWA

Tags: node.js, express, apple-sign-in

I've implemented "Sign in with Apple" on my site. When I try it on my phone, it redirects me to a blank white page with the same URL as the `redirect_uri` I've configured.

I can't find any info on why this is happening. What's a possible fix?

**UPDATE**

It seems as if Apple JS SDK is creating a FORM HTML DOM element, sets the POST URL of the FORM to point to the redirect_uri, and finally programmatically clicks form.submit(). This for some reason causes the page to navigate to the redirect_uri and show the POST response as a new page.

I figured this out by tracking the Apple JS SDK in the debugger.

Here is my code

```js
//----  Frontend ----

AppleID.auth.init({
    clientId : '<client_id>',
    scope : 'email',
    redirectURI : 'mySite.com/apple_auth',
    state : 'origin:web',
    nonce : Date.now(),
    //usePopup : true //not using this one. When false or undefined, Apple will make a POST request to the defined redirect_uri
})


// Listen for authorization success.
document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnSuccess', (event) => {
    // Handle successful response.
    console.log(event.detail.data);
});

// Listen for authorization failures.
document.addEventListener('AppleIDSignInOnFailure', (event) => {
    // Handle error.
    console.log(event.detail.error);
});

//...

myButton.onClick = ()=>{
    try {
        var res = await AppleID.auth.signIn()
    } catch(err) {
        var x = 0
    }
}
```

```js
//----  Backend ----

var appleSignin = require("apple-signin-auth")

app.express.post('/apple_auth', async (req, res)=>{
    var body = req.body
    try {
        const appleRes = await appleSignin.verifyIdToken(
            body.id_token, // We need to pass the token that we wish to decode.
            {
                audience: '<client_id', // client id - The same one we used  on the frontend, this is the secret key used for encoding and decoding the token.
                ignoreExpiration: true, // Token will not expire unless you manually do so.
            }
        )
        
        //do something with the Apple response
    } catch (err) {
        // Token is not verified
        console.error(err)
    }
})
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `redirectURI` start with `http://` or `https://`?

Comment: Your `POST /apple_auth` route doesn't send any response so why is it surprising that you see a blank page?

Comment: @Phil it does not seem to be required, as everything is working as expected, with the main issue being that the page is redirected to a blank page with the URL same as `redirect_uri`. I as as of writing this analyzing what the Apple JS SDK is doing, and it seems like it's creating a FORM DOM element  with a POST target towards the `redirect_uri` and programmatically clicks "form.submit()". I am unsure as to why this happens, but there could be a potential workaround for this.

Comment: @Phil it does not seem to matter that the POST route doesn't send a response. It should, and I added it to my latest version of the code, thanks for that note, but it doesn't change the blank-page-redirect issue. Please read my comment above this one. There's something else going on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. From [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sign_in_with_apple/sign_in_with_apple_js/configuring_your_webpage_for_sign_in_with_apple#3331292)...

   > The HTTP body contains the result parameters with a content-type of **`application/x-www-form-urlencoded`**.

   Make sure you've configured the `urlencoded()` body-parsing middleware in your Express app.

   ```js
   app.use(express.urlencoded());
   ```
2. Make sure you check for errors and actually send a response from your `/apple_auth` Express route

   ```js
   const { code, id_token, state, user, error } = req.body;
   if (error) {
     return res.status(500).send(error);
   }
   try {
     const appleRes = await appleSignin.verifyIdToken(id_token, {
       audience: "<client_id>",
       ignoreExpiration: true,
     });

     // do something with the Apple response, then send a response
     res.send(appleRes.sub);
   } catch (err) {
     console.error(err);
     res.sendStatus(500); // send a 500 response status
   }
   ```

Comment: Thanks Phil. However this does not solve the problem. Your code now only prints the `sub` value on screen.

It seems as if Apple JS SDK is not handling the response properly.

As mentioned in my previous comment: The Apple JS SDK creates a `FORM` HTML DOM element, sets the POST URL of the FORM to point to the `redirect_uri`, and finally programmatically clicks `form.submit()`. This for some reason causes the page to navigate to the `redirect_uri` and show the POST response as a new page.

Comment: Sounds like it's working exactly as intended. What do you want it to respond with?

Comment: How is it working exactly as intended if the POST response is printed on screen? According to Apple docs the form submission is supposed to resolve its await, but it doesn't get that far, because the form submission navigates to a black page with the POST data printed.

Comment: It is though. The JS SDK makes a request to Apple's API, resolves the authentication then passes the result to your `redirectURI` via a POST request. And that's exactly what you're seeing here

Comment: Well then I'm confused. What's the purpose of redirecting? What if I don't want redirecting? Why does the form.submit() redirect? How do I override it? I do not wish to be redirected. I just want a POST response that I do what I wish with. No redirect. No extra stuff.

Comment: Most OAuth flows require client-side navigation / redirection, it's just how they work. That's literally why the option is named `redirectURL`, because it redirects the client to the trusted page. Perhaps you want to use the popup option instead

Comment: Do you have any ideas on how to properly handle the redirect once it's in the hands of my app? The app need to somehow get back to the login page without disrupting the user experience flow. Currently, it's disrupted. With google and facebook, it works fine without disruption.

Comment: After you do whatever you want to do with the POST data, you could just use `res.redirect("/some/other/url")`

Comment: I've tried that, but on iOS safari as PWA it will just redirect the newely opened in-app browser. That's how PWA Safari works: When opening a new link it doesn't open native Safari, it opens an in-app Safari that user must close manually.